# How to properly implement external pagination with Angular Ui-Grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

In the example, http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/314_external_pagination, it shows "external pagination" but the code is pulling a data set of 100, and displaying all 100.

With external pagination, I thought this is what would happen:

EXAMPLE: 10,000 rows are available, but only a partial # of rows will be provided as the user navigates around the pages--- but it will still show ALL pages and total items (10,000) as if the entire data set loaded.